# How to use IAppBuilder.CreatePerOwinContext in a self-hosted 2.2 WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a working self-hosted OWIN based 2.2 WebApi project.  I wanted to put authorization into it and share the identity service with my MVC 5 website.  (There a numerous opinions on if or how easy doing so may be.)  My attempt to share the authorization/authentication cookie has lead me into a hole.  I discovered that the WebApi code was not seeing/processing the cookie even though it was in the request header.  I then decided to try a test in which I would generate the cookie in the WebApi on one call and accept it on another.  That attempt lead me to the fact that CreatePerOwinContext is not working as I thought it should.

I placed the following code in a method to generate the cookie.

```
var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
var asim = ctx.Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
asim.SignInAsync(user, false, false);
```

and discovered that the Get was returning null.  I then investigated the code in my startup

```
appBuilder.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```

I placed a breakpoint on ApplicationSigInManger.Create and never reached it.  I placed a breakpoint at the same location in my MVC 5 code and did hit the breakpoint.  Yes, I did verify that I am reaching and continuing past the call to  CreatePerOwinContext.  The lack of hitting the breakpoint has lead me to conclude that the call to CreatePerOwinContext is not working the same in WebApi as in MVC 5.

Both the MVC project and the WebApi project are using .Net 4.6 release code and the latest versions of their respective NuGet packages.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any luck in finding a solution?

Comment: @gigi I have moved on to other projects and never got that one working.  I am currently working on a IIS hosted site that has both MVC and WebAPI controllers and have managed to share the security/permissions etc. between them.  I generated a MVC 4.6 SPA site and cribbed some code into my non SPA site.  Look at the AccountController.Authorize and anything that references it.  I don't know for sure if this new information would solve the original problem or not.